# Java recursion with BST

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

So I currently am writing a program where I need to take a tree full of nodes, and basically get all of the nodes (each of them have a name inside of them that I need to obtain and then put it in an array). I am attempting to do this through recursion, and I am running into a bit of a sticky situation. Basically, my recursive call does the left side of the tree perfectly. However, when it goes to the right side (that is right side of the top of the tree, the root), it sets the index back to 2 (instead of continuing where it left off on the left side), and I am a bit confused on how I can resolve this issue. Here is my code for my method and recursive method:

```
    public Object[] getAllIdentifiers() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    current = root;
    
    if(root == null)
        return null;
    
    Object[] identifiers = new Object[numberOfIdentifiers];
    getAllIdentifiers(current, identifiers, 0);
    
    return identifiers;
}

private void getAllIdentifiers(Node node, Object[] array, int index) {
    
    if(node != null) {
        array[index] = node.id;
        System.out.println("INDEX: " + index);
    }
    
    if(node.leftChild != null) {
        System.out.println("LEFT");
        index = index + 1;
        getAllIdentifiers(node.leftChild, array, index);
    }
    if(node.rightChild != null) {
        System.out.println("RIGHT");
        index = index + 1;
        getAllIdentifiers(node.rightChild, array, index);
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My thought is that the index variable in getAllIdentifiers is not being updated globally, just in the recursive calls. So in the first call, index is still 2 because it has only been incremented twice. You could make the index variable update globally, but a more elegant solution might have getAllIdentifiers return an int so that the current index can be passed forwards across the recursive calls (rather than having it be void).

Comment: So if I use an int, how exactly would that look. I played around with that idea and every time I do that, I end up adding a return statement that stops these calls early. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the index variable is not updated globally because variables are passed-by-value. Instead pass +1 while calling the recursive function.

Comment: @RajeshPantula so when doing that it does the same thing only it starts back over at index 1 when going to the right side.

Comment: @SilentThief, I haven't actually tried it, but if you do index += getAllIdentifiers(..) and return index at the end is what I was thinking. And when adding a node to array[] you would also increment index. For the global solution, I was thinking you just increment the global variable every time you add a node to the array, and use that to determine array[globalIndex] = node.id. This would not require passing index. I still think the first solution mentioned in this comment is stylistically clearer.

Comment: Check your if condition, that is messing up the way indexes are passed. Just add a single if condition on top of your method to handle if(root == null)

Comment: @RajeshPantula how would that fix the issue? Especially because root isn't going to be null in this case? I'm very confused.

Comment: @DiegoEsparza Perfect I will give that a try thank you! And it is much easier, this is just for an assignment so I can't modify it that much.

Comment: @SilentThief: Refer this link. You can just have if(root=null) as the base case in your recursive method. No need to check if(root.left != null) while making recursive call. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-traversals-inorder-preorder-and-postorder/

Comment: @RajeshPantula So I went ahead and took your advice and it made the code make a lot more sense! However, I still seem to be having this issue. I've done some trial and error over the last few hours still to no avail. Basically it is still doing the same thing, repeating over indexes and 2 of the nodes are showing null when they should be showing the node itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first decide what kind of traversal you want for your tree(inorder, preorder or postoder) and based on that you can simplify your tree traversal like this :

```
public List<Integer> getAllIdentifiers(Node root) {
         List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
        
         preoder(root, list); // if instead of preorder, you need inorder modify your recursive method to add node first and then go to left or right subtree.
         return list; // covert this to array here if you want.
    }
    
    void inorder(Node root, List<Integer> list){
        if(root == null) return ;
        
        list.add(root.Id);
        inorder(root.left, list);
        inorder(root.right, list);
        
    }
```

use list and append the element and then generate array. it will be easier than keeping track of indexes. If you want to do this in single pass for performance reasons, pass index as a 3rd arg to the method and increment while passing to left & right subtrees.

Comment: It has to be done the way above. It is for an assignment. I can change the private methods, but cannot change the public method and have to use the tree that I created in other code that is not this.